# Is there something about Starfleet which makes them particularly susceptible to infiltration?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Spoilers for Picard and TNG in this question.

On several occasions we've seen the Starfleet command structure be compromised at an extremely high level. A few notable instances being:

- > TNG episode "Conspiracy" features infiltration of several high-ranking Starfleet officials by mind-controlling parasites.
- > Picard S3 features infiltration of Starfleet by Changelings across the entire fleet up to high-ranking officials.
- > Picard S1 features Commodore Oh as a secondary antagonist, who is actually a member of the Zhat Vash.

Is there something about Starfleet or the Federation which makes them vulnerable to these situations? It seems to keep happening.

Comment: The Klingons literally had their Chancellor replaced. It's not a Federation-only phenomenon

Comment: *in the last twenty-four months, it's been challenged by every major power in the quadrant – the Borg, the Cardassians, the Dominion. They all smell the scent of death on the Federation."*

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. The author isn't touting their own opinion; they are just asking if there is a reason why certain events occur repeatedly. Just because you have evidence that contradicts the question or you disagree with it does not mean that it deserves to be closed.

Comment: @Valorum Who was the Klingon Chancellor that was replaced?

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Kahless got replaced with clone.

Comment: @Valorum oh by "chancellor replaced" you mean divine Emperor returned.

Comment: -1 For gratuitous use of spoiler markup.

Comment: Because the Federation is the central focus of the (all the) shows and infiltration of other governments/alliances is only of passing interest to the writers.

Answer (score 4):

Out-of-universe, the *"Starfleet's highest ranks have turned into back-stabbing supervillians!"* is just a tiresome trope in which all the power figures of Starfleet are corrupt and/or compromised (Badmirals and Friends) and the lone heroes must save the day (in TNG, PIC, LOW). It can be exciting if used at the right times and in the right amounts, but this theme needs a break, at least for a while.

In-universe, a potential answer for your question is that the Federation constantly has a target on its back. Starfleet has defended it from the Klingons, the Romulans, the Borg, the Cardassians, and the Dominion. It encompasses a large swath of territory and has substantial firepower. As such, many species would want to have methods to bring Starfleet and the Federation down if there are opportunities.

However, you mentioned a few specific scenarios that I'd like to address.

1. I think that the events in "Conspiracy" were a freak accident and
   unavoidable. There could have been many ways the parasites infected
   and spread throughout the higher ranks of Starfleet.
2. Commodore Oh, as you mentioned, is a member of the Zhat Vash.
   [Screen
   Rant](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-picard-zhat-vash-origin-synthetic-armageddon/)
   states:

   > The Zhat Vash are an older faction of the Romulan secret police, the Tal Shiar, but one so secret that even the Tal Shiar consider
   > them a myth. However, the Zhat Vash have been so effective at
   > keeping their secret that they have been operating in dozens of star
   > systems - including the Klingon Empire, the Gorn Hegemony, and even
   > the United Federation of Planets - undetected for an unknown number
   > of years.

   The Romulans are usually wary and suspicious. They always want to
   know what the enemy is doing to give themselves an advantage. As
   stated in the quote, they have operatives infiltrating practically
   every power in the quadrant. Starfleet's not alone there.
3. In season 3 of PIC, it turns out that

   > Changelings have permeated Starfleet throughout its upper and lower ranks, and they are hungry for the Federation's destruction.

   There are a couple of reasons for this. The first is that the
   Federation beat them in the Dominion War. The Changelings attacked
   but lost, and in the process became vengeful. Second, we also learn that Section 31 did manufactured the Morphogenic virus and performed horrifying experiments on Changelings, causing them to mutate and
   become more dangerous.

   In this case, the Changelings are at fault for attacking and the
   Federation also suffered from some of its own previous actions.

Starfleet isn't the only group that experienced internal strife. The Klingons had numerous power struggles, including, of course, the Klingon Civil War. In addition, during the Dominion War, the Cardassian government was essentially mutilated and many Cardassians were slaughtered.

In summary, Starfleet has almost constantly been under threat. I don't think it's particularly susceptible to infiltration; it has just had a lot of unfortunate circumstances. It's lucky that nothing worse happened.

Comment: I'd also add that Obsidian Order and Tal'shiar were practically destroyed and severely crippled during Dominion war.  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Die_is_Cast_(episode)

Comment: The best thing about the "cliffhanger" at the end "Conspiracy" is that it was never mentioned again. (And if it was, I'm not at all sorry to have missed it.)

Comment: As I understand it there was a writer's strike that made them shift course and swapped the parasites for the Borg